# Duvida em leitura de Matriz por arquivo em C

Tags: c

Eu tenho que fazer a leitura de uma matriz 48X2 por um arquivo `.txt`, o arquivo tem essa estrutura:

```
nome_da_pessoa
1 2
3 4
...
N N
```

Em que N são os elementos de posição 47, eu preciso salvar o nome da pessoa em uma variável, e salvar a matriz em outra variável, para realizar essa tarefa, fiz o seguinte algorítimo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define Lin 48
#define Col 2
int main(){

    int i, j, Mat[Lin][Col]; 
    char nome[30];
    FILE *arq;

    arq=fopen("matriz.txt", "r");
    fgets(nome, 30, arq);// pega o nome do participante
    for(i=0;i<Lin;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Col;j++){
            fscanf(arq,"%d ", &Mat[i][j]);
            printf("%d ", Mat[i][j]);//testar se a impressão esta correta
    }
    }
    fclose(arq); //fechar arquivo
    return 0;
}
```

Entretanto, quando eu imprimo a variável `Mat[i][j]` o programa imprimi a matriz com os números um do lado do outro, ou invés de 48x2. Gostaria de saber qual o meu erro, e o que deveria fazer.

Comment: Depois do `}` que fecha o `for` interno, adicione `printf("\n");`

Comment: Você nem mesmo precisa fazer `"%d "`, com esse espaço em branco final, no `fscanf()` porque espaços em branco são ignorados pela função

Comment: Ah, entendi, eu estava colocando o `printf("\n")` dentro do for interno, mas ai ficava um número embaixo do outro, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O seu código está faltando um `\n` (significa "new line", ou seja, "nova linha") no caso ele ficaria assim `printf("\n");` após o primeiro for.

Ele irá executar o código sabendo que Lin é 48 e Col é 2 ele irá executar o primeiro for que é o da linha (48 vezes) e depois entrará no for da coluna, após o término das 2 colunas por linha aí você acrescenta o `\n`. (Caso contrário ele irá manter os números tudo em sequencia, um no lado do outro)

**Segue abaixo um exemplo do código:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define Lin 48
#define Col 2
int main(){

    int i, j, Mat[Lin][Col]; 
    char nome[30];
    FILE *arq;

    arq=fopen("matriz.txt", "r");
    fgets(nome, 30, arq);// pega o nome do participante
    for(i=0;i<Lin;i++){
        for(j=0;j<Col;j++){
            fscanf(arq,"%d ", &Mat[i][j]);
            printf("%d ", Mat[i][j]);//testar se a impressão esta correta
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(arq); //fechar arquivo
    return 0;
}
```